# How do I target and remove a Subject from an Observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm using a service to collect user responses from a questionnaire.  The way everything flows is like this

1. **questionnaire.component.ts** : main container that recieves data from `question.service.ts`
2. **question-shell.component.ts** : Component used by `questionnaire.component.ts` to iterate questions.
3. **Misc input components** : Several components to suit different types of input data which sends useer response back up to `question-shell.component.ts` through and `@Output()`
4. **question-shell.component.ts** : recieves response and sends to `answer.service.ts`.
5. **answer.service.ts** : recieves data and stores in a variable named `_formList`.

The `question-shell.component.ts` class looks like this

```
export class QuestionShellComponent implements OnDestroy {

    @Input() Data: Question;  //receives data from questionnaire.component

    Response     : UserResponse = {}; //stores user responses



    constructor( private _ans: AnswerService ){}

    ngOnDestroy(){
        this.removeResponse();  //triggers if component toggled off
    }

    grabAnswer(event){          // gets user response from Output on
        this.Response = event;  // input component and stores in Response
        this.sendResponse();
    }

    sendResponse(): void{    // adds response to answer.service
        this._ans.addResponse(this.Response);
    }

    removeResponse(): void{  //removes response from answer.service
        this._ans.deleteResponse(this.Data.id);
    }
}
```

The `answer.service.ts` file looks like this

```
export class AnswerService {

    private _formList = new Subject<any>();
    public FormList = this._formList.asObservable();

    constructor( private http: Http, private afdb: AngularFireDatabase ){}

    addResponse(event:any){
        this._formList.next(event);
    }

    deleteResponse(event:string){    //the only thing that made sense to try so far

        let target = this._formList.observers.findIndex(a => a.id = event );

        this.FormList.observers.unsubscribe(target);

        console.log(target);

        //let target = this._formList.observers.findIndex( a => a.id = event );

        //this._formList.observers.find( a => a.id = event ).unsubscribe();

        //this._formList.observers[target].unsubscribe();
        //console.log(target);
    }

}
```

Everything loads to the `answer.service.ts` file successfully.  I'm calling the `OnDestroy` method because it's possible a user may change their mind about an answer and select a different one, which may close a tier of questions and open another.  As of right now if you keep switchining back and forth it keeps adding more instances of the same questions so I need to delete them if the component closes.

As of right now I'm getting an error saying

> Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined.

I originally tried to only target `_formList` which gave me a result in the `console.log()` with an error telling me

> this._formList.observers.unsubscribe is not a function

I found `unsubscribe()` trying to find the right way of using `splice()` thinking that was what I needed to use.  I'm just lost now.  Everything else is working fine and the console is logging the response sent from the component's `OnDestroy` method so this has to be where the problem is.  If you need to know more about what's going on with the components let me know and I'll post more code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter to drop data from your Observable.

this._formList.observers.filter(data => (filter logic))

Comment: would I use `.splice()` or `.unsubscribe()` somehow in the "filter logic"?

Comment: you can define the filter logic\ condition which returns true or false

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

**component.ts**

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';

export class Component {

    private _formList = new Subject<any>();
    private subscription: Subscription;

    deleteResponse(event:string){
         this.subscription = this._formList.observers.findIndex(a => a.id = event );
         this.subscription.unsubscribe(); 
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        this.eventManager.destroy(this.eventSubscriber);
    }

}
```

Comment: I just updated the post to be clearer about how everything is set up.